# Linear regression: How to demand similar MSE across different subgroups?

Tags: regression, anova, linear, regularization, loss-functions

In typical least square regression, we want to minimize  $||y-\hat{y}||$

where

$\hat{y}=B*x$

I am now working on a car fleet management problem, $y$ can be split into several groups (in my case, cities). When I minimize $||y-\hat{y}||$, there is a chance that $B$ targets at one single group, because that group contributes more to the total error. Consequently, my model ($B$) is over-fitting toward a certain sub group of the samples. In the car fleet context: the predictive model might predict NYC very well, but very badly for LA

People normally run cross-validation to address this problem. However, I don't think CV can solve the problem completely: the problem comes from the fact that the input data is not generated from the same process.

What I believe is that, there need to be another term in the cost function:

$||y-\hat{y}|| + \lambda * VaranceOfMseAmongSubGroups() $

But I don't know how to implement this idea.

Can anyone provide any insight here?

Comment: Do you have a good result of you model LA by itself? If not, then you indeed have a serious difficulty adding the LA data into the entire regression model.

Comment: @JamesPhillips if I fit LA alone, then the fitted model is better than the 'all together' model